# Scala 2.8.0 toolchain

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I've currently spent the best part of my day grappling with dependency hell; something I haven't really experienced in a while.  I'm attempting to use Scala 2.8.0 as per [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066682/what-frameworks-to-use-to-bootstrap-my-first-production-scala-project), and the fact that I intend to use Actors - for which the fork/join pool seems to be faster (according to community buzz, anyhow).

The problem I'm facing is the supporting toolchain: I'd like to use configgy and querulous for configuration management and database abstraction, respectively.  I cannot for the life of me find versions of these libraries that support 2.8.0.RC6; or at least, not versions that I can get working.

I tried [the semi-official branch](http://github.com/robey/configgy/tree/scala-2.8) of configgy, but that hasn't been updated since Beta1.  I also tried [ijuma's fork](http://github.com/ijuma/configgy/tree/), but that's still on 1.4.3.  I've just noticed [jboyen's fork](http://github.com/jboyens/configgy/tree/), which appears to be up to date, so I'll give that a go when I get home tonight.

For querulous, I found [a 2.8 fork](http://github.com/bwmcadams/querulous/tree/), but that then spiralled into its own set of dependency problems with the advent of xrayspecs and configgy both being required.

Am I looking in the wrong place?  I can't find up-to-date versions of these libraries in the scala-tools nexus, nor in any other maven repositories.  I'd much prefer to use 2.8.0 over 2.7.7, but at this point in time I'm ready to fall back on stable and forward-port my code at a later date (which is a bit of a pain in the ass, given how close 2.8.0 is).

I guess the questions are: can anyone advise me where I might be able to find 2.8.0 compatible versions of these libraries please?  And while RC6 is out now, is anyone able to offer a ballpark (weeks/months?) prediction as to when 2.8.0 will go final?

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066682/what-frameworks-to-use-to-bootstrap-my-first-production-scala-project "the answers to this question"
  [2]: http://github.com/robey/configgy/tree/scala-2.8 "robey's 2.8 configgy port"
  [3]: http://github.com/ijuma/configgy/tree/ "ijuma's 2.8 fork"
  [4]: http://github.com/jboyens/configgy/tree/ "jboyen's 2.8 fork"
  [5]: http://github.com/bwmcadams/querulous/tree/ "bwmcadams' port"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will be an "issue" for most libraries out there for the coming weeks: They will have (if they chose to do so) to upgrade.

Some do it regularly ([scalatest](http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/org/scalatest/scalatest/) or [specs](http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/org/scala-tools/testing/specs_2.8.0.RC6/1.6.5-SNAPSHOT/)). Other won't until the final release.

As for the prediction for the final Scala 2.8 release, you have [this recent message from Martin Odersky](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Status-of-2-8-td2263878.html#a2263878) (June 22nd):

> Timeline: We will wait one more week to get feedback on RC6.
>   We will push out RC7 early next week.
>   If no further problems show up RC7 would then turn into 2.8 final 10-14 days after it is released.

As I said, mid-July at best.

---

And... this release date mentioned above shouldn't be too much off the mark:
**[Scala2.8 around the corner](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.internals/3684)**

> From: martin odersky 
>   Subject: 2.8 final around the corner
>   Newsgroups: gmane.comp.lang.scala.internals
>   Date: 2010-07-13 14:45:30 GMT (2 hours and 25 minutes ago)

Hi all,

> RC7 has been out two weeks. We looked at all tickets reported against it and concluded that it is good to go.
>   **We will run some final tests today and tomorrow and, if everything goes well will turn the RC into the final version of 2.8.0.**
>
> Cheers
>
> -- Martin

Comment: Thanks for that.  I guess at this stage I'll target 2.7.7, as the turnaround on this project needs to be a couple of weeks (it's small, but it's a good chance to start learning Scala).  I'll upgrade to 2.8.0 at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

Failure to see branches:

```
http://github.com/ijuma/configgy/tree/scala-2.8
```

Most recent commit message:

```
Update to Scala 2.8.0.RC6.
```

Comment: Although I admit I have no idea what "still on 1.4.3" refers to.

Comment: Configgy is up to 1.5.2 now (IIRC); the 2.8.0 branch still uses Configgy 1.4.3 :).  As in, changes from master haven't been pulled into that branch since they started maintaining it.